# 2 Phase zero time switch

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay

I'm trying to build an instant or zero 2 pole switch (DC current). Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is that when the switch is powered off, the lines are connected like shown in the first picture (The color of the same circles displays the connected sides). When you turn on the switch, the lines are connected like in the second picture. The closest thing that I found out is a solid state relay due to its high-speed switching time. I need the high-speed switching time, as the device on the other end isn't allowed to turn off or reboot.[image: Switch diagram]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. (1) When asking for a solution to a problem you need to write a specification. In your case you need to specify the switched voltage, current, acceptable switching time (zero is not an option) and frequency. (2) Also some details on the supply (battery, PSU, SMPS, etc.) and load (resistive, inductive, capacitive, battery, etc.) is essential. (3) Your diagram is, uhm, a little unusual around here. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. (4) What kind of rebootable device can tolerate a polarity reversal? i.e., Explain the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Any DPDT should be able to do this

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to build an instant or zero 2 phase switch (DC current).

For switches we use the word "pole" for each circuit. You are looking for a two-pole changeover switch.

No switch is instant. You'll have to specify an acceptable transfer time.

A relay *might* suffice but your specification is too vague at present.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiBEky.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A relay can provide polarity reversal.*

You can add some capacitance on whichever side is guaranteed to maintain its polarity. This will ride out the brief interruption during switching.

Comment: The transfer time need's to be less than 10ms. And thank you for the circuit. This is exactly what I need. Now I just need the calculate the right capacitance. And sorry if I misspelled some things. This is more of a hobby that I like to do, as it's fun making your own electronics.

Comment: +1 for the general principle. Be careful with adding capacitance- make sure the current through the contacts (eg. to charge the capacitance you are adding, or the capacitance in the source or load) is limited to something reasonable for the relay type. Otherwise you might be making a capacitive discharge welder for the contacts. Tungsten load rated relays are more tolerant of surges (read the datasheet). Sticky contacts are not fun.